# How to get all SQL Server instances using Node JS?

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I am trying to get all the SQL Server instances in a network. In my application, user will select the particular SQL Server instance and a database on that server.

So is there any package or driver to do this in Node.js?

Comment: It's probably easier to write a simple .NET command-line program that runs `System.Data.Sql.SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance .GetDataSources()` and returns it in stdout which is then read from your NodeJS program.

Comment: We are not having .NET, how to integrate this?
We only having node js and MS SQL.

Comment: "We are not having .NET" - even for a tiny command-line utility program that has only 5 meaningful lines of source-code which you can compile and run from a Bash shell on Linux with minimal tooling? Sounds like you work for a dogmatic organization. Dogma is bad.

Comment: Sorry, this is not for an organisation or any company project. I am developing application for my self-learning purpose. So, could you please help to do this on node js coding?

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Apparently `SqlDataSourceEnumerator` is not in .NET Core - only .NET Framework, so it isn't cross-platform - so disregard my remarks about using or writing a simple .NET Core utility program</sub>.

While researching how `SqlDataSourceEnumerator` works (via [this thread](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/17)) I found [this project](https://github.com/mrsquish/SqlBrowserClient) which is straightforward to port to NodeJS... which I've done below:

```
const BROADCAST_ADDR = '192.168.0.255'; // Use ifconfig/ipconfig to get your broadcast address.
const SQL_BROWSER_PORT = 1434;

const dgram = require( 'dgram' );

async function discoverSqlServers() {
    
    // SQL Browser responds to a single-byte message of 0x02:
    const message = Buffer.alloc( /*size:*/ 1, /*fill:*/ 2 ); 

    const udp = dgram.createSocket( 'udp4' );

    // Set-up the listener before sending the UDP message:
    const messages = [];

    udp.on( 'message', function( incoming, remote ) {

        messages.push( incoming );
    } );

    try {
        udp.setBroadcast( true );
        
        try {
            await sendAsync( udp, message, SQL_BROWSER_PORT, BROADCAST_ADDR );
        }
        catch( err ) {
            throw; // TODO: Graceful error handling.
        }
    
        // Wait for 10 seconds for responses.
        await delayAsync( 10 * 1000 );

        // Parse and return any messages received:
        return messages.map( parseSqlBrowserMessage ).filter( e => e !== null );
    }
    finally {
        udp.close();
    }
}

/** Promise wrapper over dgram.send */
function sendAsync( udp, message, port, address ) {
    
    return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
        
        udp.send( message, 0, message.length, SQL_BROWSER_PORT, BROADCAST_ADDR, function( err, bytes ) {
            if( err ) { reject( err ); }
            else return resolve();
        } );
        
    } );
}

/** Promise wrapper over setTimeout */
function delayAsync( time ) {
    
    return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
        setTimeout( resolve, time );
    } );
}

const sqlBrowserRegexp = /[^;]*ServerName;(?<ServerName>[\w\d]+);InstanceName;(?<InstanceName>[\w\d]+);IsClustered;(?<IsClustered>[\w]+);Version;(?<Version>[\d]+\.[\d]+\.[\d]+\.[\d]+)(;tcp;(?<tcp>\d+))?(;np;(?<np>[^;]+))?;;/gi;

function parseSqlBrowserMessage( message ) {

    const m = message.match( sqlBrowserRegexp );
    if( m && m.groups ) {
        return ( {
            name: m.groups.InstanceName,
            version: m.groups.Version,
            tcp: m.groups.tcp, // TCP/IP
            np: m.groups.np // Named Pipes
        } );
    }
    
    return null;
}
```